# Probability of 2 items being manufactured at same location

Tags: probability, independence

Need some help with the below problem:
Probability of an item being produced at location X is 70% and that of being produced at location Y is 80%, then what is the probability that 2 items are produced at the same location?

I understand that production of 1st and 2nd item is independent of each other and also that being produced in location X and location Y are disjoint events. However, I am having trouble tying up these two concepts together for the problem. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Note: This was a question asked to one of my friends during an interview with a big tech firm. I confirmed with him and indeed this was the problem. Not sure if it was a trick question though.

Comment: Being produced in factory $X$ and being produced in factory $Y$ are indeed disjoint events. As such, it is impossible for $P[X] + P[Y] = 0.7 + 0.8 = 1.5$ to be greater than 1. Can you check the problem again?

Comment: Maybe the problem implies that a product can have been produced both in X and in Y (your breakfast cereals are made of wheat that has grown in a field in X before been processed in a factory in Y) and in that case being produced in X or in Y are NOT disjoint events ?

Comment: the events are indeed disjoint, an item can only be manufactured at any one location at one time. i.e. it can be either location X or location Y. The problem is finding probability that any 2 items are produced in the same location.

Comment: The problem as presented has no complete solution as the given probability measures are not sensible.  The sum of probabilities for disjoint events cannot exceed 1, as the values given do.  The post needs to be checked and reposted with needed corrections to the values or the events they represent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp let's for the sake of it change the probabilities to 30% for X and 40% for Y. However, I find it hard to understand how does the underlying logic of the solution depend on the values. I mean shouldn't they be acting just like placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing $P[X] + P[Y] = 1$, which is the only reasonable case (as @jvdhooft points out), then the probability the two are manufactured in the same location (out of only $X$ and $Y$) is $P(XX) + P(YY)$. Let $P[X] = p$ thus $P[X] = 1-p$. This is then just an ordinary Bernoulli process so
$$
P[XX] = p^2, \ \ P[YY] = (1-p)^2,
$$
and therefore
$$
P[XX] + P[YY] = p^2 + (1-p)^2 = 1 - 2p + 2p^2.
$$

Comment: how is P[Y] = 1-p, which in this case would be 1-0.7=0.3, and not 0.8, which is what was given.

Comment: @pratik "Supposing $P[X]+P[Y]=1$, which is the only reasonable case (as jvdhooft points out)"

Answer (score 0):

As these are independent variables, you multiply the probabilities of them being produced at one location and add this to the product of the probability of them being produced at the other location. So the probability of the item being produced at location $X$ is $(7/10)*(2/10)= 14/100$, which is the probability of the items being produced at the same location. The probability of both items being produced at locations $Y$ is the $3/10 * 8/10 = 24/100$. Therefore the total probability of them being produced at the same location = $14/100 + 24/100 = 38/100$.

Comment: I don't get your reasonning at all. $(7/10)∗(2/10)$ seems to be the probability that item A is produced in X and item B is not produced in Y, which doesn't answer the question of the OP.

Comment: I assumed that OP meant there were two items with each probability being that of being manufactured at two different locations. I may have misinterpreted the question, though

Comment: Hum, I see, that would give sense to the problem. Let's wait for clarification from the OP !

Comment: I didn't quite get the logic of multiplying 0.7 with 0.2 and 0.8 with 0.3. Shouldn't it be 0.7 *0.7 for location X and then 0.8*0.8 for location Y?

Comment: Is the probability of item1 being manufactured at X .7 and the probability of item2 being manufactured at Y .8? Or is the probability of an item being manufactured at X .7 and any item being manufactured at Y .8?

Comment: the latter - probability for any item (be it 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and so on) at location X is 0.7 and for Y it is 0.8

Comment: disregard my answer then, it isn't what you want